Is there a way to control how often messages are sent to the LSPs?
I'm looking for a way to reduce the amount of messages (reduce the frequency) that are being sent to the LSP.
It feels to me that messages are sent too often with no meaningful changes in the code. Which makes Neovim to become sluggish and less responsive in insert mode.
